# Issues installing Haskell package with C dependencies (glpk)

Tags: haskell, ubuntu-18.04, cabal, glpk

The Haskell package `Numeric.LinearProgramming` depends on the C library `glpk`. Upon attempted installation on Ubuntu 18.04 with command `cabal install hmatrix-glpk-0.19.0.0` the following error appears:

```
Resolving dependencies...
Notice: installing into a sandbox located at /home/owen/.cabal-sandbox
Configuring hmatrix-glpk-0.19.0.0...
Failed to install hmatrix-glpk-0.19.0.0
Build log ( /home/owen/.cabal-sandbox/logs/hmatrix-glpk-0.19.0.0.log ):
cabal: Entering directory '/tmp/cabal-tmp-7470/hmatrix-glpk-0.19.0.0'
Configuring hmatrix-glpk-0.19.0.0...
cabal: Missing dependency on a foreign library:
*Missing C library: glpk
This problem can usually be solved by installing the system package that
provides this library (you may need the "-dev" version). If the library is
already installed but in a non-standard location then you can use the flags
--extra-include-dirs= and --extra-lib-dirs= to specify where it is.
cabal: Leaving directory '/tmp/cabal-tmp-7470/hmatrix-glpk-0.19.0.0'
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
hmatrix-glpk-0.19.0.0 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

I have `glpk-utils` installed in the standard spot (by APT) `/usr/share/doc/glpk-utils/`, but as recommended I tried adding the `--extra.../path to glpk-utils` tags but it failed with same message.

What could be the problem here? Is `glpk-utils` the correct package installation? Is it not visible to Cabal? Something else?

Comment: You may need to install libglpk-dev

Comment: Problem solved!

Comment: @Hogeyama Maybe add that as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install `libglpk-dev` package.

For the difference between `libglpk` (which is required by `glpk-utils`) and `libglpk-dev`,
please refer to https://askubuntu.com/questions/1008912/whats-the-difference-between-dev-package-and-ordinary-package, for example.
Usually, Haskell FFI requires `-dev` packages as said in the error message.